# How to store second dropdown value in database

Tags: forms

```
function YOUR_FUNCTION_THAT_DISPLAYS_FORM(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $query_state=db_select('state', 's');
  $query_state->fields('s',array('State_code','State_name'));
  $query_state->orderBy('State_name','ASC');
  $state_results = $query_state->execute();

  $options_state = array();

  // Using fetchAll() you can iterate through a result set.
  while ($state_record = $state_results->fetchAll()) {
    // You want state code as key, not state name as key.
    $options_state[$state_record->State_code]=t($state_record->State_name);
  }

  // State form element.
  $form['state1']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#options' =>$options_state,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
      'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  // City wrapper form element.
  $form['city_element_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}




// AJAX callback function.
function _ajaxfunction(&$form, &$form_state) { 
  $key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;

  $query_city=db_select('city', 'c');
  $query_city->fields('c',array('District_Code','District_Name','State_Code'));
  $query_city->condition('State_Code', $key, '=');

  $query_city->orderBy('District_Name','ASC');
  $city_results = $query_city->execute();
  $options_city = array();


  while ($city_record = $city_results->fetchAll()) {
    // This is correct.
    $options_city[$city_record->District_Code]=t($city_record->District_Name);
  }

  // Render city setting.
  $form['city_element_wrapper']['city']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('District'),
    '#options' => $options_city,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  return $form['city_element_wrapper'];
}
```

I have tried to get city value like this `'city_element_wrapper' => $form_state['values']['city_element_wrapper']['city']`, but error is coming like

> Notice: Undefined index: city_element_wrapper in
>   form_test_custom_form_submit()

How to solve it?

```
function form_test_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $prog_id =1;

  db_insert('tot_prog')->fields(array('state1' => $form_state['values']['state1'],
'city_element_wrapper' => $form_state['values']['city_element_wrapper']['city'],) // i have metioned like this,  is correct???? but its shows error, how to get the select city value???
        ->execute();
 drupal_set_message("successfully saved Settings"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

> Notice: Undefined index: city_element_wrapper in
>   form_test_custom_form_submit()

means that index `city_element_wrapper` is missing in `$form_state` variable. Do this:

```
function form_test_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $prog_id =1;

  db_insert('tot_prog')
    ->fields(array(
              'state1' => $form_state['values']['state1'],
              'city_element_wrapper' => $form_state['values']['city_element_wrapper']['city'],
            ) )
    ->execute();

  drupal_set_message("successfully saved Settings"); 
}
```

Always take the **reference** of `$form` variables if you want to fetch values from the variables or update the values of the variable. For more details about PHP reference read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).